# I want to put a specific z-index depends on the value of my data for my series with the echarts lib for laying my bar from the lower to the higher

Tags: javascript, angular, echarts

I'm trying to put a specific z-index for my config where the z-index is based on the value of my bar. for example if i have an array of [8,10,5] who represented my 3 bar for the abs 1. I wanna have the bar on the order of [5,8,10] [my series obj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNkcu.png)

I try to put my data series into one array and then turning this array into an obj and basing my z index into the value of the obj like this :

z: serie.map((value) => obj[value])

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551); instead, give us a proper [mre] of your issue, please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.